# Why isn't the 2-Sylow subgroup of $D_5$ not normal when it is unique?

Tags: group-theory

$D_5 = \{1, a, a^2, a^3, a^4, b, ab, a^2b, a^3b, a^4b\}$

The subgroup is $\{1, b\}$ and as far as I can tell, this is the only one. I don't understand why this isn't normal?

Comment: What about $\{1,ab\}$?

Comment: @user1337 Right. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

to be normal we must have $xbx^{-1}\in H=\{e,b\}$, I use $e$ rather than $1$, for all $x$, is this the case? No because
$$abb(ab)^{-1}=abbb^{-1}a^{-1}=aba^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-2}=ba^{-2}$$
which is not in $H$